# How to get the data from log file using udp appender

Tags: java, udp, appender, wowza

How to send log details by using udp appender in wowza Media Server . i have uncomment the   udp appender in log4j.properties and added serverAccessUDP to root. but i Cant view the result.Where i Can Get the Result?
Anybody Help Me
Thanks in Advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using .Net framework,Udp Appender is easy to Access the Log File,Here the link

[Udp Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.UdpAppender.html)